How can I save both weights and model definition with PyTorch?
First, I defined a model use pytorch and I saved it.
class SimpleNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleNN, self).__init__()
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(28 * 28, 128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(128, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64, 10)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.fc(x)
        return x

torch.save(model, "my_model.pth")

but then loading the model also requires that the model class (here, SimpleNN) to exist in the current file. For example, you directly use below in another file to load model without the model class
model = torch.load("my_model.pth")

It will report an error like this
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'SimpleNN' on <module '__main__' from ····

But when I use torchvision.models and save model like this
from torchvision.models import resnet18

model = resnet18(pretrained=True) 
torch.save(model, "resnet_model.pth")

Then I use direct loading in another file like this
resnet = torch.load("resnet_model.pth")
print(resnet)

It does not require the model class, and can be successfully loaded, and contains both model structure and weight information.
So my question is

How to achieve this?
Can my model also do this, that is, the pth file contains the model structure and weight information, and does not need to declare the class in advance?


pytorch-saving-both-weights-and-model-definition I know there is a similar question here, I have read it but it does not solve my problem

the resnet model definition is not loaded from the pth file, the code for it is already in  from torchvision.models.resnet18 . The pth file only tells your code to go look for it there.
Similarly, your SimpleNN module was defined in the python file (which by convention is the module __main__), so the code will look for it there, and not find it
You cannot store a model definition in a pth file. Model definition has to be in code.

Please don't add new information in comments. Take the [tour].

If you save the model object, the model class definition must be available to load the model object. This is true both for your custom model and the resnet model. The resnet example works because torch.load tries to import the definition from torchvision which presumably exists in the namespace, while loading your custom model tries to import the definition from __main__ which errors as it doesn't exist. This isn't a pytorch issue, it's a python issue.
If you want to save a single file that you can load without imports, you need to compile the model to a different format. Easiest would be torch script, but you can also use onnx:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class SimpleNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleNN, self).__init__()
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(28 * 28, 128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(128, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64, 10)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.fc(x)
        return x
    
model = SimpleNN()
model_script = torch.jit.script(model)
torch.jit.save(model_script, 'my_model.pt')

And later when loading:
import torch
model = torch.jit.load('my_model.pt')

Note that this converts the model from a standard pytorch model to a scripted model. If you need to load the standard pytorch model, you need to have the model class definition in the namespace.
